# Javascript + JQuery: Object properties are undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm trying to build a simple web app using JQuery. I'm trying to make an ajax request to the server the following way:

```
function getClients() {
    return $.ajax('/api/v1/clients',
                  {
                      headers: {
                          Authorization: 'Token ' + getCookie("auth_token")
                      }
                  });
}
```

I also do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(getClients());
});
```

So that I can see the result of my request. In the console I see the following:

```
{
  "readyState": 4,
  "responseText": "{\"count\":2,\"next\":null,\"previous\":null,\"results\":[{\"id\":2,\"group_set\":[1],\"first_name\":\"b\",\"last_name\":\"b\",\"username\":\"b\",\"telegram_id\":null,\"phone\":null,\"picture\":null,\"blocked\":false,\"telegram_user\":null,\"user\":2,\"source\":null},{\"id\":1,\"group_set\":[1],\"first_name\":\"a\",\"last_name\":\"a\",\"username\":\"a\",\"telegram_id\":null,\"phone\":null,\"picture\":null,\"blocked\":false,\"telegram_user\":null,\"user\":2,\"source\":null}]}",
  "responseJSON": {
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "group_set": [
          1
        ],
        "first_name": "b",
        "last_name": "b",
        "username": "b",
        "telegram_id": null,
        "phone": null,
        "picture": null,
        "blocked": false,
        "telegram_user": null,
        "user": 2,
        "source": null
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "group_set": [
          1
        ],
        "first_name": "a",
        "last_name": "a",
        "username": "a",
        "telegram_id": null,
        "phone": null,
        "picture": null,
        "blocked": false,
        "telegram_user": null,
        "user": 2,
        "source": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK"
}
```

(This output is made by clicking on "Copy object" in Firefox).
However, if I change getClients() as shown below:

```
function getClients() {
    return $.ajax('/api/v1/clients',
                  {
                      headers: {
                          Authorization: 'Token ' + getCookie("auth_token")
                      }
                  }).responseJSON;
}
```

Then in the console I will get

```
undefined
```

Also, when I try to use the object's properties in code, I get an error that the properties are undefined.
How is that and how do I fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: What's your problem exactly? Are you just trying to access the JSON values from the response?

Answer (score 1):

getClients returns promise. Your code:

```
return $.ajax(...).responseJSON
```

reads responseJSON from promise object which is undefined. Promise returns result only when it is resolved (then())

You should leave getClients as is and change part in document ready like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  getClients().then(function(response) {
    const respJson = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(respJson.responseJSON);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `getClients()` function as seen below:

```js
function getClients() {
    return $.ajax('/api/v1/clients',
                  {
                      headers: {
                          Authorization: 'Token ' + getCookie("auth_token")
                      }
                  });
}
```

Then use [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to select properties:

```js
var clientData = getClients();
var jsonData = clientData["responseJSON"];

var results = jsonData["results"];

console.log(results[0]["first_name"]); // Logs the "first_name" value from first results array
```

Since your JSON properties are strings, Bracket Notation is required. Otherwise, you could use, for example: `clientData.responseJSON`

Comment: .... is ajax async?????  I assume you need to use [.then()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

Comment: Hence, you cannot use the returned promise as a json result

Comment: So how do you expect `clientData` to contain the result of the asynchronous function?

Comment: @Barmar Have you seen the question? Doing: `console.log(getClients());` returns all of the JSON data. I think OP had trouble selecting the properties.

Comment: He's seeing that in the console, which has a dynamic link to the Promise, and shows the properties that were updated after the response was received.